# Eclipse_Cucumber: "No editor descriptor for id cucumber.eclipse.editor.editors.Editor"

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium, cucumber

I am trying to run my test in eclipse using cucumber BDD with selenium webdriver.

There is no code to paste as there are no errors in my code.The problem is that the cucumber feature file is not getting recognized(with a light green color) and I can see this error "No editor descriptor for id cucumber.eclipse.editor.editors.Editor" .

I expect the green icon to be there so that I can run it as a cucumber feature.Also when I try to run my test by clicking "Run as"-I cant see any option to Run it as a cucumber feature.Looks like some of the features haven't been installed successfully but am struggling to find out which ones!

Versions used: Eclipse oxygen,Java 9,selenium 3.8.0,installed cucumber plugin and with Maven.I have also put the required dependencies in the pom.xml and all the relevant jars are added in the build path. Is there anything I might have missed.Please help. Also do let me know if there is a way to attach screenshots in here so that I can attach it for your reference.

Comment: may be cucumber plugin issue. reinstall and try again. which cucumber plugin have you installed?

Comment: I have installed plugin from here: http://cucumber.github.com/cucumber-eclipse/update-site by adding this url into the eclipse install new software window.

Comment: Install the natural 0.7.6 from eclipse marketplace.